# Azure Devops : workitem ID formatting

Tags: azure-devops

On Azure Devops taskboard, is it possible to format the workitems' IDs on the work items, i.e. to display 11,104 instead of 11104 to make them more readable?

[image: ID example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no method can format the work item IDs using **`,`** symbol on the cards of Kanban Boards.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving our Azure DevOps products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will open a feature request as you suggest.